# App crashes transitioning scenes swift sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, transition

I am building an app that has a main scene and a restart scene. The main game scene uses sprite kit physics to have an object controlled by the user float across the screen. When it rashes into an obstacle the app transitions to the end scene using:
 self.presentScene.restartscene. 
This works just fine. then the restart scene has a restart button. when this is clicked the app transitions back to the game scene using:
self.presentscene.gamescene 
i know this presents the original scene because i did an ns log to make sure. The problem is when this original scene is presented again the scene changes colors multiple times alternates very quickly between one and two nodes on the screen and then crashes. I have no idea the cause. i have had this problem before and i know other people have. no one has given me a definite answer. i hope one of you guys will. Thank you. help needed badly!!!!!!!

Comment: I think you may have a memory leak, are you disposing or reusing the scenes or just creating new ones every time?

Comment: how do you dispose of the scene?

Answer (score 1):

Try to navigate between scenes this way:

```
let nextScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "SceneNameHere")!
scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene)
```

Also please check your code on startup in the gamescene.
May be you are using some global flags to store value for win/fail/restart conditions and your scenes simply open together one by one (it is hard to say without checking actual code).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the original seen from view after transitioning away from it. Use this code:

```
 myView.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Hope this helps :)